How to make a subprogram return to the main program
I'm creating a rock  paper scissors game which consists of a subprogram containing the single player game, which is stored on a different file and imported to the main program which runs it. In the single player game the player has the option of returning to the main menu which is part of the runner file however i cant work out  how to allow the player to do this. Any suggestions?
I tried to import the runner file into the singleplayer program and call a function from runner there but it caused an error: NameError: name 'runner' is not defined
Code for Runner file:
#RPS Runner
from RPS_singleplayer import *
from RPS_multiplayer import *

#The actual runner
def runner():
    exitCalled = False
    print("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors")
    print("Main Menu \n1. Singleplayer\n2. Multiplayer\n3. Exit")
    grabUserInput = int(input("Enter an option:"))

    while exitCalled != True:
        if grabUserInput == 1:
            print("taking you to singleplayer mode... please wait")
            singleplayer()
        elif grabUserInput == 2:
            print("taking you to multiplayer mode... please wait")
            multiplayer()
        elif grabUserInput == 3:
            exitCalled = True
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid Input. Try Again")
            grabUserInput = int(input("Enter an option: "))
runner()

Section of code from singleplayer file:
choice = input("Would you like to play again or return to menu? Y/N/M?: ")
    if choice == "y" or choice == "Y" or choice == "yes":
        rpscpu()
    elif choice == "n" or choice == "N" or choice == "no":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        quit()
    elif choice == "M" or choice == "m" or choice == "menu":
        runner()


Just have singleplayer return the result which can be checked from your runner function.

Be careful with words like "program".  It looks like you are not actually exec-ing a new process, so there is only one program running and you are just asking about returning from a function.

The traditional term was "subroutine", but in modern programming we call them "function".

If you want to ask about the NameError, make a [mre]. In the process you might find the problem yourself :) Otherwise you can ask a new question. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

In the "Section of code from singleplayer file", you have an indentation error. I'm assuming that's just a copy-paste error and choice should be indented, plus the context is missing and it should be def singleplayer(): followed by the game code (which is unimportant to the question). Please [edit] to clarify. You can copy the ...  # Game code here from my answer if you want.

Related: How to go back to a previous part of the code in Python?

Note: The code is incomplete and it's not clear why you got a NameError, but the question is still effectively answerable, though I'll need to make some reasonable assumptions.

"Program" is a misnomer: singleplayer is actually a function. The way to return from a function is to use return, of course. (If this is new to you, any good Python tutorial should cover it, for example in the official tutorial: Defining Functions, towards the end of the section.)
There are two problems with your current design of singleplayer:

Python has a recursion limit that you could hit by calling singleplayer and runner back and forth. It's 1000 by default, so users are unlikely to hit it, but regardless it's good practice to avoid recursion where not necessary.

Control flow. Imagine you want to write an additional runner script that just launches one single-player game then exits. The way your code is written now, if the new runner runs the single-player game contained in singleplayer, then at the end, instead of simply exiting, it's going to show the user that prompt.
Additionally, as a rule of thumb, only the main code should be able to exit a program. (This is normally in def main but here you have it in def runner.)


So singleplayer should just return, instead of prompting the user.
def singleplayer():
    ...  # Game code here
    return


By the way, you might want to have it return the result of the game so that the runner can create stats like "percentage of games won by user" for example, but that's beside the point.

Then, the runner can handle the process of running singleplayer again if needed. Here's a bare-bones example:
if grabUserInput == 1:
    print("taking you to singleplayer mode... please wait")
    while True:
        singleplayer()
        choice = input("Would you like to play again? Y/N: ")
        if choice == "n" or choice == "N" or choice == "no":
            break

Then you would need to make the main menu actually loop, like to start, put the "Main Menu" print inside the loop.
For related tips, see Asking the user for input until they give a valid response
